# Modifying code from ArcGIS Story Maps

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, story-map

I am looking to make a map from our online ArcGIS sites and host them on our own server. I got that all done, but I am trying to modify the code to my liking. There is a section in github (https://github.com/Esri/storymap-series) that goes over this which seems pretty self explanatory, sans one issue.

I can't seem to find where the map is declared. It says under application life cycle to look for the custom JavaScript code block at the far end of the index.html. The example they provide and the sites I got from our own ArcGIS does not have that code anywhere. Can't seem to find it in the .js files either.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Apologies, it looks like the Readme is outdated. Custom javascript now goes in a file called `custom-scripts.js`, found [here](https://github.com/Esri/storymap-series/blob/master/src/app/custom-scripts.js). We'll change the Readme to reflect the current state of the app.